# How can you cause a combobox to loose focus?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am developing a windows forms project in vb.net. I have added a comboBox to my form. the form automatically focuses on the comboBox. Nothing I click on causes the comboBox to loose focus. I do not want the form to focus on the comboBox because I do not want users to change the selected text in the comboBox by accidentally moving the scroll wheel.

I have tried:

```
comboBox1.CanFocus = False 
comboBox1.Focus = false
```

These properties are not write-able.

```
InvokeLostFocus(ComboBox1, New EventArgs)
```

This does not throw a compiler error but it does not seem to do anything either (focus stays).

I am really stuck and can not find anything on SE or google. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to focus another control. Note that the form itself cannot be focused.

Something like:

```
label1.Focus()
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  
    Me.ActiveControl = label1;       
End Sub
```

You can even try to disable and enable the ComboBox.

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. I am not sure if labels can be focused on or not so I also tried: TextBox1.Focus(). This does not work either.

Comment: Thanks! the second option works perfect. The focus on the combobox is lost. I tried to vote up but I do not have enough rep :(